# how to reduce rmse while performing Linear Regression in python

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am not really a coder but this is what I have so far. I'm trying to apply linear regression to predict something from a sample data. I'm probably doing some mistake here since I'm getting an rmse of above 1. I've checked the correlation among the continuous variables which turned out to be quite small reaching to a max of 0.2. Also checked for outliers using the Inter Quartile Range method but there were none.

Please can someone tell me how should I reduce the rmse?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df_hosp = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\LAPPY-2\Desktop\LengthOfStay.csv')

df_temp, df_test = train_test_split(df_hosp, test_size=0.30, train_size=0.70)
df_train, df_val = train_test_split(df_temp, test_size=0.30, train_size=0.70)

X = df_train[['rcount', 'male', 'female', 'dialysisrenalendstage', 'asthma', \
              'irondef', 'pneum', 'substancedependence', \
              'psychologicaldisordermajor', 'depress', 'psychother', \
              'fibrosisandother', 'malnutrition', 'hemo', 'hematocrit', \
              'neutrophils', 'sodium', 'glucose', 'bloodureanitro', \
              'creatinine', 'bmi', 'pulse', 'respiration', \
              'secondarydiagnosisnonicd9']]

y = df_train['lengthofstay']

model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=True, copy_X=True)
m = model.fit(X, y)

predictions_train = m.predict(X)
print('Score: %.2f' % m.score(X, y))
rms_train = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, predictions_train))
print ('Training set RMSE: %.2f' % rms_train)
```

**Output:**
Score: 0.75
Training set RMSE: 1.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `y` variable is the length of stay, there is no reason why it should have an `rmse < 1`. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/RootMeanSquaredError) is a resource explaining the formula definition of RMSE. You can see that if `(y_pred - y)` is on average bigger than 1, then your RMSE is going to be bigger than 1.

As for why this is happening, you appear to be attempting to fit a model with a large number of variables, sum of which are not actually correlated with your output variable. You should only fit a model on data which is actually correlated because a correlation implies that the input data somehow affects the output data.

Try limiting the number of input variables you fit to, starting with the most highly correlated data.

Comment: Thanks @pypypy. Agreed on rmse formula part, but it is showing as under 0.5 if I don't split the data into various parts. I removed few of the variables which were least correlated with the target variable but still the output is the same.

Comment: X = df_train[['rcount', 'hematocrit', 'neutrophils', 'bloodureanitro', \
              'respiration', 'male', 'female', 'dialysisrenalendstage', 'asthma', \
              'irondef', 'pneum', 'substancedependence', \
              'psychologicaldisordermajor', 'depress', 'psychother', \
              'fibrosisandother', 'malnutrition', 'hemo' ]]

Comment: Is this real data? If so there may be no relationship to be found, there is no reason why the data has to fit a linear regression.

Comment: this data is actually used to prepare a linear regression model in R and has a solution ready. just that I'm trying to implement in python

Comment: How do the results compare?

Comment: Could not compare the results since the model in R has already a dashboard created but it's more like a sample and the actual results are restricted